# Javascript EventListener trigger click event if clicked on area where no other event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Suppose I have a webpage with some areas which are triggering events on mouse ckick like opening subpages while click into the menu area or opening images/galeries while clicking into the content area etc.

But there are some areas within the page where no other event are triggered - and I want to create an EventListener that triggers only if clicked into an area where no other event is triggered, in this case to close an overlay sidebar div.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. What I understand from your question is you would like to add eventlistener to an area where there is no eventlistener exist. Simple select the area using ID or tag elements and add eventlistener click to it and add your desired operation inside the function. If you don't get my point feel free to share your code link. We will guide you further. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I need. I need an event listener that will check if there is another event listener in the clicked div and only run if there is no other event listener.